# WinForm is shrinking on different users computers

Tags: c#, winforms, window, .net-4.5

I have a windows form program that I have started to release on the internet to people. Some users are having an issue with the form not displaying at the correct size, but instead much smaller. an example is shown below

https://mediacru.sh/kJ_xEebSDki-.png <=== broken size
http://puu.sh/9flwS/9804c56898.jpg <=== How it should look

I have attempted to reproduce this on my computer with different screen resolutions, different screens and different DPI settings, with no success.

[edit] installer for the program can be found here - http://infinitehavoc.co.uk/starlaunch/Starlaunch%20setup.exe [/edit]

Any help is appreciated. I am completly lost on this.

Comment: Did you try setting `AutoScale` property of the form to None? It does the following: "Gets or sets a value indicating whether the form adjusts its size to fit the height of the font used on the form and scales its controls" as per [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autoscale.aspx) .

Comment: no i didn't, I will try this if Sascha 's solution doesn't work

Comment: I strongly believe that autoscale is the reason for your problem.

Comment: Not when it is *this* much smaller.  Autoscaling stops past 125% unless the program explicitly declares itself DpiAware.  And scaling affects both height and width.  It's a bug, nobody can debug code from a screen-shot.

Comment: @HansPassant the code that i have entered doesnt touch the screen size, thats why I didn't post any, if you really think it is needed though, I can post the code, but it is messy, barely commented and very typical of someone new to programming.

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic setting autoscale to false has fixed the issue it seesms. if you post it as an answer, I will mark it as correct for other people who get this issue and so you get the rep for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `AutoScale` property of the `Form` to `false`. In my experience, it usually works when you are loading some content other than `Controls` that is scaled based on the font settings of the Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the MinimumSize of the Window to the size you prefer, not just the "current" Size. So it cant get below your desired values.

Comment: Size was defined in the visual editor in the "size" property. A test version is being downloaded to a user who has this issue to test fix :)

Comment: try finding the entry MinimumSize in the Editor or try to set it manually in the constructor of the class. and @Daniel Kelley I DID provide a possible solution, and sorry if that seems offensve...

Comment: setting the minimum size didnt change the screen size, made it so that button images didnt shrink with the button, so the sides get cut off https://mediacru.sh/S9TAoFFWttqy.png

Comment: Okay then try to set the Size in the Load or in the Activated method. I think for some reason the window gets resized on startup. Try to find a method which is called AFTER initialising the window and THEN set the Size again.

Comment: @Sascha the autoscale method has fixed the issue, thanks though :)